Magento 2 : checkout page is blank after upgrade magento 2.4.5 to 2.4.6p5
After upgrading, I encountered an issue with the checkout page. After adding the product to the cart and proceeding to checkout, the page appears blank without any data. It doesn't even show any errors in developer mode despite having display errors enabled. I'm using the Argento theme.


hard to say .. with any product ? are you familiar with debugging ? or with API (in order to try another way of validating the order) ? the last one could help know if it comes from the process of checkout and its data (common between API and normal way) or from templating issue, like when a custom overridden template doesn't work with the new version. cheers

Have you check by disabling the third party extension into website?

Seems like you have upgraded PHP version while upgrading Magento version, and a required PHP extension has not been installed.
Otherwise, try to disable any custom modules/extensions which are involved while loading the checkout page.
